# A convex quadrilateral causes minimal total distance to vertices at the intersection of diagonals

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Given a convex quadrilateral, prove the point on the plane with minimal total distance to the four vertices (that is, summing each of the four distances) is the intersection of the diagonals.

*This problem was posed by Hadamard.  My proof is below.  It seems to me simpler than the existing proofs, and so I request verification and critique.*

Given points $A,C$, for all points $P$, $PA + PC \leq AC$.  Equality is reached for any point on segment $AC$.

Consider quadrilateral $ABCD$, with diagonals $AC$ and $BD$.  From the above, if the two diagonals intersect at point $I$, no point on the plane has lower $IA + IC$, and no point on the plane has lower $IB + ID$, so clearly no point on the plane has lower $IA + IB + IC + ID$.

---

**Update** *Reworded as per advice of Calvin Lin:*

Given points $A,C$, for all points $P$, $PA + PC \geq AC$, with equality iff $P$ is on segment $AC$.

Consider quadrilateral $ABCD$, with diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersecting at $I$.  For any point $P$:
$$
PA + PC \geq AC = IA + IC \\
PB + PD \geq BD = IB + ID
$$
with $I$ being the unique point in $AC \cap BD$ and therefore having equality in both equations.  Therefore, for $P \neq I$, $$
PA + PB + PC + PD > I.
$$

Comment: Can you add an image to illustrate/clarify what you are saying? Presumably the quadrilateral is $ABCD$, so if you want $PA + PB \leq AB$, then $P$ lies on line segment $AB$ (as opposed to being on the diagonals).

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks.  Fixed to use standard convention of quadrilateral $ABCD$ with diagonals $AC$ and $BD$.

Comment: The edited solution is fine.   $\quad$ Some clarity on what you mean by "no point on the plane has lower $IA+IC$", esp since it doesn't involve the point. You likely mean "For any point $P$ on the plane, $PA + PC \geq AC = IA+IC$". $\quad$ It's the standard solution I'd expect. EG If you do an online search, that's the one that shows up.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for the excellent suggestions.   Rewording accordingly.